# ArcPy: Using lblclass expression to change font style and color

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, arcpy

I´m trying to label features of a dataset using ArcPy and the **lblclass** function.
While commands like "VBNewline" and "Round" work pretty well, I´m not able to change colors or font style. An expression that works in ArcMap doesn´t work in the script. 
Could anyone help me out please? 
I´m using ArcGIS 10.0

Code that works:

```
 #Adding Labels
    layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "")[0] 
    if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        for lblclass in layer.labelClasses:
            lblclass.className = "Flaeche"
            lblclass.expression = "[FID] & VBNewLine & Round([AREA_mm2],2)"
        lblclass.showClassLabels = True
    layer.showLabels = True
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Code that works in ArcMap but not in ArcPy

```
#Adding Labels
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "")[0] 
if layer.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
    for lblclass in layer.labelClasses:
        lblclass.className = "Flaeche"
        lblclass.expression = ""<CLR red='255' green='0' blue='0'>" & [FID] & VBNewLine & Round([AREA_mm2],2) & "</CLR>""
    lblclass.showClassLabels = True
layer.showLabels = True
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't work because Python interpreter doesn't understand two double quotes in a row.
Instead you can try this:

```
lblclass.expression = '"%s" & [FID] & VBNewLine & Round([AREA_mm2],2) & "%s"' % ("<CLR red='255' green='0' blue='0'>", "</CLR>")
```